# How to continue iteration in nested foreach

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

Here is my simple example:

```
IList<string> files = new string[] { "file1", "file2", "file3" };
IList<string> words = new string[] { "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth" };

foreach (var file in files) {
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var word in words) {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        i++;
    }
}
```

After every iteration, I want to see in the MessageBox `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`, `16`, `17`, `18` but it gives me 3 times `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`

Is it possible which I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why the counter "*resets*" itself is because you instruct it to do so:

```
foreach (var file in files) {
    int i = 1;               //<--- for each file, reset the counter i to 1
    foreach (var word in words) {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        i++;
    }
}
```

You can get the behavior you aim by initializing the counter outside the outer loop:

```
int i = 1;                   //<--- initialize outside outer loop
foreach (var file in files) {
    foreach (var word in words) {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Small details cause big problems like this. Thank you very much.